# Regex for replacing everything after a keyword with colon up to any other keyword with colon

Tags: regex

I have the following type of strings:

```
This is a test: 1, two again,three test2: what is, this
test: acid, kool-aid word: some more info
Another test: face, 3, & yes
```

What I'd like to do is remove `test:` and everything after until it hits another word that has a colon.

The result set from above would look like:

```
This is a test2: what is, this
word: some more info
Another
```

Here's what I've attempted, but this fails when there is NO word with a colon (so example 3 fails)
`test:.+?(?=\w+:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching:

```sh
 *\btest:.*?\b(?=\w+:|$)
```

And replace with empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aNQeFC/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `*`: Match 0 or more spaces
- `\btest:` Match full word `test:`
- `.*?\b`: Match 0 or more of any characters (lazy match) followed by a word boundary
- `(?=\w+:|$)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have a word + `:` or end of line ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. For the last case where there is no second word with a colon, you need to match on the end-of-line character `$`. So you can use:

`test:.*?(?=$|\b\w+:)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZMz9mP/3)

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following regex. This will create 1 to 2 capturing groups, this is having 3 matches 1st from starting to just before text with colon's 1st occurrence comes, 2nd match: From text followed by colon to next occurrence of text followed by colon(no capturing group is created for this match). 3rd match: rest of the value. So in case line has only 2 matches found(nothing in value after 2nd occurrence of text colon) then it will create 1 capturing group else it will be having 2 capturing groups. Perform substitution accordingly.

```
^(.*?)\s*\w+:.*?(?:\w+:|$)\s*(.*)$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/Q8SO1N/1)